# How many points are necessary to achieve level 50 on Fitocracy?

Tags: fitocracy

I know I'm not leveling up as fast as I used to, but when I see someone at level 50 I don't know if they have twice as many points or ten times as many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 2,582,350 -- more than 30 times as many points as are required for level 25. [Here is a spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cgttr05haylzez/Fitocracy-levelling.xlsx?dl=0) that gives the point levels required for levels 1-60. It also contains a calculator for approximating how long it will take you to reach each level.